# Regular Expression for comma-separated ids and range

Tags: regex

I have a filter that has a field that lets you enter either a comma-separated list of ids or a range of ids. For example, "1,2,3" and "4-9" are valid ids. I wrote the following regex for this:

```
/(^\d+(?:[,]\d+)*$)|(^\d+-\d+$)/.test(str)
```

where str is the string I am evaluating. This works fine and returns the correct boolean for all scenarios except when in a range, the first id is larger than the second. For example, 12-10 is an invalid range, but the above regex does not return false.

Is there a way to validate that using regex at all? I can obviously split the string on '-' and compare the two parts, but will lose the brevity regex provides.

Answer (score 3):

"The brevity that regex provides" is probably not worth the complexity that it will introduce.  This seems to be a pretty well-defined problem and splitting first on `,` and then on `-` for each element seems like a pretty straightforward and effective approach.

Answer (score 2):

Solving that problem isn't a job for regular expressions.

Extract the ranges using a regex, then validate afterwards.